# Где мои 100 очков репутации за ассоциацию с сетевым аккаунтом?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, reputation

Если на одном из аккаунтов в сети Stack Exchange имеется 200 или больше репутации, то при регистрации на любом сайте выдаются 100 очков репутации. Я их не получил.

Собственно, где мои 100 репы?

Comment: Наверное, тут так же, как и с ru.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я обновила учетные записи на ru.stackoverflow.com и rus.stackexchange.com. Бонусные очки выданы всем, у кого есть 200+ репутации в сети Stack Exchange. (Репутация на мете должна обновиться в течении часа.)

Новые пользователи, приходящие из Сети Знаний, могут не получить бонус. Я посмотрю что как через несколько дней.

Comment: Если бы это произошло раньше, не пришлось бы полагаться на автопреобразование-тривиальных-ответов-в-комментарии на ru.SO...